# Do I need to do modrewrite in order for this to work?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, mod-rewrite

I'm working with the facebook api. Looking at the documentation on the site [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#read).

Look at the example that you need to connect to via http post:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/recipebox:cook?
recipe=http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

But, the "recipe" (really an MLB game) in my case has a link of:

```
http://www.sportannica.com/team.php?team=New York Yankees&year=2012
```

Do I need to use modrewrite to make my link compatible with its place in the facebook graph url? having another question mark in the URL kinda messes things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, try using [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) on the URL you pass for the `recipe` parameter.

```
$recipeurl = 'http://www.sportannica.com/team.php?team=New York Yankees&year=2012';


$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/recipebox:cook?recipe=' .
       urlencode($recipeurl) . '&access_token=1234';
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. But, for the $recipeurl, inside of the file that the $recipeurl send me to, do I need to have open graph tags in there for it to work?

Comment: That part I don't know; try first and see the result.

Comment: Strange. That didn't give me an error. So, I suppose that it solved my problem. But, I notice that it didn't post anything to my feed on FB.

Comment: Might try to post another question in that case if its somewhat separate from this question.  I know nothing about facebook, sorry.